# Sorting differences between SQL Server & ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

We are implementing a solution for search-only purpose with ElasticSearch to remove some load from the SQL Server database we have.

The issue I have here is that when I sort a document on SQL Server, its not the same order as in ElasticSearch.

Results:

SQL Server sort is : - ! # & @ _ 0 1 a A b

ElasticSearch sorts : ! # & - 0 1 @ _ A a b

The mapping of the field I sort on:

```
description": 
{
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "notAnalyzed": 
    {
      "analyzer": "ipStrictAnalyzer",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "analyzed":
    {
      "analyzer": "ipAnalyzer",
      "type": "string"
    }
}
```

The analyzer:

```
"ipStrictAnalyzer": 
{
  "filter": ["lowercase","trim","ipSynonym"],
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "ipStrictTokenizer"
}
```

The tokenizer:

```
"ipStrictTokenizer": 
{
  "type": "keyword"
}
```

The ipSynonym filter is really just a synonym filter with an empty file right now.

```
"ipSynonym": 
{
  "type": "synonym",
  "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
}
```

The order by I send:

```
"sort": 
[
{
  "description.notAnalyzed": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
],
```

Can we customize that?

Thanks in advance,
Matthias.

Comment: Can you please add more details as elastic search sorting depends on type of field and analyzer.

Comment: Is this enough information? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like `ipSynonym` filter is altering search result as normal sorting should match database sorting as both must be using unicode(?) encoding. I would suggest you to play by removing the filter and analyzer.

Comment: Can you share the definition of your `ipSynonym` filter?

Comment: Informations added. I did not have the time to test without the filter & analyzer. I'll take time when I can to do that.